# how to avoid duplicated column in two different tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

OK, I'm inexperienced in terms of database design, so hopefully my question isn't too silly.

I have 2 tables `users` and `user_profiles` these two tables has one-to-one relation between them. so(obviously) each row in `users` table will be linked to a row in `user_profiles` table.

And, when I'm displaying a user's profile in the web app I'm creating I have to do two `SELECT` statements(or `JOIN`) to get the required data, which is -somehow- overkill for me, and I'm looking for an alternative to it, I'm trying to get the required data with one `SELECET` statment from one table.

**`users` schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**`user_profiles` schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_profiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

So for example, if I want to grab the nickname, user and email I'll definitely use `JOIN` or double `SELECT`. Which will lead me to use two tables for such a simple query.

**So, I have currently three solutions in mind:**

1. Use `JOIN` or `SELECT` and hopefully my website won't be too slow
   because of this.    Will this have huge impact on the performance of
   my web app anyway?
2. Remove `user_profiles` table and keep all user's personal data in
   one table.
3. Duplicate columns in two tables, so for example the `email` column will be present in `users` and `user_profiles`. Which will result in double `INSERTS` at the time of user registration.

Looking forward to hear your opinions.

Comment: Definitely 1.  That's how things are supposed to work in a relational DB, therefore it won't be slow.  (Or, if you are really sure that the contents of `user_profiles` depends only on `user_id`, than merge the tables.  This will depend on your use case.)

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to have a 1-1 relationship beteween tables. Fix your design to have user and user profile in 1 table.

Comment: Can a user have more than one profile?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov Nope, only one.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you incorrectly identified relationship between `users` and `user_profiles`;  I usually see it's either 1:0..1 (user can -but doesn't have to- have at most one profile) or 1:0..n(user can have many profiles). Surely, if it's really 1:1 in your system, it makes sense to get rid of `user_profiles` and add `nickname` to `users`.

There is nothing wrong with having `join` in the query, as **dezso** mentioned in comments, it's RDMS main purpose and responsibility to perform such operations in fast and reliable way.
Also, in my understanding there are just very few places in the system where you need to retrieve information from `user_profiles`; normally you just display basic information from `users`.

Finally, if it's 1:0..1 relationship, there is absolutely no need in `user_profiles.id` column - `user_profiles.user_id` should be primary key and foreign key to `users`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove user_profiles table and keep all user's personal data in one table.

the user_profiles table is not storing any data about the nickname itself and you say a user can have no more than one nickname. I assume the nickname is optional.  The only reason to have it in a separate table MIGHT be for performance to get a list of nicknames such as when a new nickname is created to check it hasn't been used already. But I doubt keeping it in a separate table is the best way to handle that.